# Slipstream updates and feature updates to Windows Server Essentials 2016

Tags: windows-update, windows-server-2016, dism, slipstream

I have a physical disk of Windows Server Essentials 2016 RTM.

How can I slipstream the monthly cumulative updates and the feature updates like 1703/1709/1803, so that a new ISO will install the latest, patched version of Windows Server Essentials 2016?

Comment: You would have to install Windows Server 2016 Essentials, install the current feature updates, then create your own ISO after that is performed.  You do that by using DISM, how you create an ISO from your current installation, is a well documented process.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, I was going to follow the steps [here](https://gist.github.com/PatrickLang/f8f3486cbbb49e0bb3f9c97e491c3981) but couldn't tell how to make it work with feature updates. Do you have a link to a guide for your approach? Do I need to install it on the actual server I intend to use, or can I do it in a VM until I create the ISO, and *then* install on the physical server?

Comment: There really isn't a guide, other then the documentation to use DISM, to create your own .WIM file.  Everything has been published by Microsoft.